# like_count for a facebook post

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am working on a social media management system, one thing we do is that we get the number of likes each post has, that used to work but after the updates of the previous 2 years
we are starting to get into troubles,

can you please give me the proper way of getting the like_count of facebook page posts and displaying them on the graph explorer?

ps: i don't want the FQL query to get the lke_counts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **likes** connection of a post to get the number of total likes a post has received. This will return a list of all people that have liked a post. To make it even easier for you, you can pass in the parameter `summary` with its value set to 1 to get the total count of likes.

Take this as an example URL
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=19292868552_10150189643478553%2Flikes%3Fsummary%3D1